# Unable to access "_ngcontent-c1" elements using protractor

Tags: protractor, cucumber, bdd, cucumberjs

Unable to access the below element

```
< input _ngcontent-c1="" name="field1" value="" type="text" >
```

I declared and access the element as below, But unable to access the element.

```
Format1: this.loginTextBox = $("input[name='field1']");
                   (or)
Format2: loginTextBox  : element(by.name('field1')),
```

And in step definition I called it as:

```
  expect((login.loginTextBox).isPresent()).to.eventually.be.false;
```

While executing the above condition got pass. can anyone help me on this....

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `**` means commented line.
If so, everything looks correct. You are expecting that element is not present and due the commented input the assertion returns true.